# Migrating .netframework NserviceBus endpoint service to .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nservicebus, topshelf

I have .net framework 4.6.1 nServiceBus endpoint that runs as service. I am also using Top Shelf for hosting the console app as windows service . I have it is setup in such a way:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureEndpoint.Configure();
    }
}

internal static class ConfigureEndpoint
{
    internal static void Configure()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(configure =>
        {
            configure.Service<EndpointSetup>(service =>
              {
                  service.ConstructUsing(s => new EndpointSetup());
                  service.WhenStarted(s => s.OnStart("connectionString"));
                  service.WhenStopped(s => s.OnStop());
                  service.WhenShutdown(s => s.OnStop());
              });
            //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
            configure.RunAsLocalSystem();
            configure.EnableShutdown();
            configure.SetServiceName("endpointName");
            configure.SetDisplayName("endpointName");
            configure.SetDescription("endpointName");
            configure.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
            {
                recoveryOption.RestartService(5);
            });
            configure.OnException(e =>
            {
                var logger = LogConfiguration.GetLoggerConfiguration();
                logger.Error(e, "Unhandled Exception Exiting");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            });
        });
    }

public class EndpointSetup
{
    private static IEndpointInstance _endpointInstance;

    public void OnStart(string connectionString)
    {
        AsyncOnStart(connectionString).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private async Task AsyncOnStart(string connectionString)
    {
        var endPtConfig= new EndpointConfiguration("endpointname");
        endPtConfig.EnableInstallers();
        InitialSetup(endPtConfig, connectionString); //<- basic setups
        CustomizeMessages(endPtConfig); //<- conventions and routings for nservice bus 
        CustomizeContainer(endPtConfig); //<-- register business related services

        _endpointInstance = await Endpoint
            .Start(endPtConfig)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void OnStop()
    {
        _endpointInstance?.Stop().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _servicePublisher?.Stop().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I want to migrate the above service to .net core 3.0 service. All the migration articles and tutorials I have seen online are for web Apis.

I know that I need the `Program.cs` Do I need `StartUp.cs` class?
Which part of the above setup need to change ? I am a bit confused here on how to proceed.
Any links to examples are appreciated.

Comment: Ok while looking online I also saw that TopShelf might not be needed in .net core 3.0  since  “worker service” concept got introduced. can be seen in this article : 
https://medium.com/@jackwild/net-core-windows-services-with-topshelf-74e8bfc3315e
still  confused  . .  .